# How do I add a Report column with data derived from a method call or dll call

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, dataset, reporting

I am maintaining a report in VS 2013 that gets user data from a table in sql using c#. It is connected to sql and has a dataset for the table.

The report displays the data, however now I want to add the user name. The user name is not stored on the table. I seem unable to add another field to the dataset as it is tied to the table. My plan was to add a field and populate it upon load from a dll call or from the following VB code...

```
Public Function getname(lanid As String) As String
    Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
    Dim appNameSpace As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace

    Dim recip As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient
    Dim ae As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry

    app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
    appNameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    recip = appNameSpace.CreateRecipient(lanid)
    recip.Resolve()
    Try
        ae = recip.AddressEntry
    Catch ex As Exception
        getname = "Not found"
        Exit Function
    End Try

    Dim name As String
    name = ae.Name
    getname = name
End Function
```

I have tried the following but I just get an #error in the column...

1, Added references to the MS DLLs required for above
2, Added this code to custom code section
3, Added a column and set the expression to
=Code.getname("F468s8")

What is wrong? What is the correct way to derive data from a method call or is this too complicated for a report?

It looks like the dataset is based off the table so I cannot add a column to that with a view to filling in the data before I display the report?

I guess the overall question for you report experts is, how would you code this. All I need is a simple example of how to call an inline method/dll OR do I need to create a new dataset and manually populate that first? I did not see an easy way to add a separate dataset.

I also tried creating a hashtable with the user data I needed but I seem unable to reference this in the CODE section of the report.

I am new to reporting (in case you had not realized)!!!

Thanks in advance
John